# Tar directory gives me error, won't let me tar!

Tags: centos, tar

[root@centosvm01 /]# tar --create --exclude="storage/thumbs/" --file="storagebackup.tar" storage/
tar: storagebackup.tar: Wrote only 8192 of 10240 bytes
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

I am trying to backup the entire /storage directory but exclude /storage/thumbs/

Answer (score 9):

Just a guess: is your disk full?

Comment: That would be my guess as well.

Comment: Also, add `-v` to the tar command to see each file as it's added. It might help you see where it's breaking.

Comment: /storage isn't full, i know that